# NextJS Videos not loading without a page refresh when the page is accessed via a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

## Problem

Hi. [muse.ai videos](https://muse.ai/docs#embed-player) are not loading on-page, when the page with a `video` embedded is accessed via a `NextJS` link.

I have a minimal reproducible example on StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-x13dy2?file=pages%2Findex.js).

### Example

If you start on `page-index` (which contains a `video`), then navigate to `page-2` (which also contains a `video`), `page-2-video` will not load the `video` unless the `page` is refreshed after navigating to it.

It might be an issue with loading externally embedded content in a `NextJS` app.

The embedded video component and the link to the second page:

```
<main className={styles.main}>
  <div
    class="muse-video-player"
    data-video="pj4AW2W"
    data-logo="0"
    data-title="0"
    data-search="0"
    data-autoplay="1"
    data-loop="1"
    data-volume="0"
    data-width="100vw"
  />
  <script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js" />

  <Link href="/pagetwo">
    <a>PAGETWO</a>
  </Link>
</main>
```

What should be rendered:
[image: Image of a video]

And what actually is:

[image]

#### If you navigate between the two pages and refresh the page, then you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

muse.ai developer here. The issue here may be that you don't instantiate the player element after you render your `Home` component.

If you have a simple static page then adding the `<script>` is the way to go. It would wait for the DOM to load, look for any element that has `muse-video-player` class and render all of them accordingly. However, if you have a page that dynamically manipulates the DOM, which is what React does, then importing the lib via `<script>` won't have any effect.

I'd recommend adding a simple `Player` component that instantiates the player after rendering. For the most basic React app you need two steps described below.

First, import the dependency inside the `<head>` of your `public/index.html`:

```
<head>
  <!-- Other stuff -->
  <script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Second, define a component, for example, in `src/Player.js` and instantiate the player after the component is mounted.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Player extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    window.MusePlayer({
        container: element,
        video: this.props.video,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div class="muse-ai-player"></div>
  }
}

export default Player;
```

You can now render players for arbitrary videos on your `src/index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Player from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Player video="pj4AW2W" />
    <Player video="VBdrD8v" />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This was the end result with the code above:

[image]

Comment: I'm just about to implement this! I do however wonder if there is an equivalent hooks / functional solution.

Comment: It may be possible to achieve with `useEffect`. You should then probably pass `[props.video]` as the second argument to `useEffect` to only run the init logic once and not after every render.

Comment: I'm having some issue with styling the resultant video. Here's an updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-x13dy2?file=Components%2FPlayer.js . I'm not sure how to set the video dimensions to consistently load a full width or autoplay, despite props being set.

Comment: I see a couple of issues. First, when passing properties to `<Player>` component, you should not use `data-` prefix. Just use `width="100%"` etc. Second, your CSS is preventing the 100% stretch. Either use `align-self: stretch` on flex container's child or don't use flex and simply use `display: block; width: 100%` on the parent. Here's a modified fork of your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-dupppk?file=pages%2Findex.js

Comment: I've managed to refactor the example from a class-based component to a functional-component. If you check over it, I could post it as an alternative answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-nsai5j?file=Components%2FPlayerFn.js

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a functional-component / hooks approach to the same question.** A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-nsai5j?file=Components%2FPlayerFn.js) to illustrate the answer.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';

export default function PlayerFn(props) {
  let fragmentRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let domNodes = fragmentRef.current;
    window.MusePlayer(
      {
        container: domNodes,
        video: props.video,
        logo: props.logo,
        title: props.title,
        width: props.width,
        search: props.search,
        autoplay: props.autoplay,
        volume: props.volume,
        loop: props.loop,
        style: props.style
      },
      [props.video]
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <script src="https://muse.ai/static/js/embed-player.min.js" />
      </Head>
      <div ref={fragmentRef} class="muse-ai-player" />
    </>
  );
}
```

And how to embed the component:

```
<PlayerFn
          video="pj4AW2W"
          logo={false}
          title={false}
          search={false}
          autoplay={false}
          loop={true}
          volume={100}
          width="100%"
        />
```